# Why do js files sometimes load with errors?

Tags: javascript, json, amcharts

I use several script libraries on [this site](https://quanthill.ru/), including Amcharts for instance. 
I have noticed that sometimes they don't load properly and there can be no table or no chart. I have tried to place them both in header and footer, but it doesn't change anything. Is there a way to make it correct?

Answer (score 2):

You have the following snippet in the `head` of your html :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(window).on('load',  function() {
        new JCaption('img.caption');
    });
</script>
```

But jQuery itself is loaded at the end of body which is causing this to break. Load jQuery in the head before this snippet. Or place this snippet at the end of body after jQuery loads.

Comment: Thank you. I have placed all the scripts at the end of the body, but still have the same problem

Comment: `ReferenceError: JCaption is not defined`. Check whether this module is present in your imports.

Comment: `JCaption` is not present? Are you missing the reference to a JS file?